# fixing the first two tr rows in the tbody

Tags: html, css

Hi i have been trying to fixed scrolling for first two  rows in . It works fine for the first row if i give css as

```
tbody>tr:nth-child(1) {position:fixed;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;} .
```

Then if i try to make the second row also fixed with the following css

```
tbody>tr:nth-child(2) {position:fixed;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;}
```

The whole table collapses. fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/CrSpu/4347/

Answer (score 0):

An element with a **fixed** position takes it's wrapper from the document. You have not given it position values like **top, left, right, bottom** so it behaves almost like a float elemnt. You need to use **position relative** on a wrapping element, like the tbody, then put your first two rows as **position: absolute**;

You also need to consider that when you use fixed\absolute positioning the 3rd row and forward ignore the first two rows as if they don't exist so you need to take into consideration the height and set their positions correctly. I am also unsure how your first two rows will react on the x-axis with an absolute\fixed position.

Personally I think you're making a mistake attempting this on tables. You could attempt just setting **overflow-x:scroll**; on your table to make it scrollable on the x-axis if it's too wide.